# sending a message by socket in python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working on Python Socket programming and I have a problem with the `send()` function. I'm following this: [Python socket network programming](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/06/python-socket-network-programming)

```
# send a thank you message to the client. 
c.send('Thank you for connecting')
# Close the connection with the client
c.close()
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*.py", line 27, in <module>
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: are you on python 3?

Comment: yes I'm on python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python 3 `send` takes a bytes object.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send

`c.send(b'Thank you for connecting')`